# Replace Unicode apostrophe in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation

I am trying to replace Modified Letter Apostrophes - nchar(700) with an empty character for a legacy system that cannot handle uniocde, but my replace is not working.

I am doing this in SQL Server Express 2019.

I have been using a function to do the replaces, but to make sure it wasn't just the function (which is working for other replaces of unicode characters), I used the following code fragment:

```
print replace('canʼt',nchar(700),'X')
```

and the result I am getting is: can't (which interestingly enough is the ASCII ' not the Unicode Modified Letter Apostrophe).

I have confirmed that the string has the modified apostrophe looking at the string in a hex editor feature of Notepad++ (the value is CA BC).

Any ideas why this isn't working in SQL?

Thanks,
David

**WORKAROUND:**

I got the replace to work with the following code, but this is not very "pretty":

```
    DECLARE @ReplaceString nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @position INT, @nstring NCHAR(12);  
    SET @ReplaceString = N'canʼt'
    SET @position = 1;     
    WHILE @position <= LEN(@Replacestring)  

    BEGIN
       IF UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString,@position,1)) = 700
       IF @position < len(@ReplaceString)
            SET @ReplaceString = SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString,1,@position - 1) +             
                  SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString,@position + 1,len(@ReplaceString))
       ELSE
            SET @ReplaceString = SUBSTRING(@ReplaceString,1,@position - 1)
       SET @position = @position + 1;  
    END
```

Comment: I executed the following `SELECT replace(N'canʼt' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN,N'ʼ',N'X')` which did work. Did not work without the collate specification. As I have limited knowledge in this matter, I cannot give you a thorough and detailed explanation (hence the comment). Note that most collations have an associated `BIN` collation. No need to specifically use the `Latin1_General_???` collation set, use the binary collation associated with the collation you are using.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you.